# Is it ok to change subnet name in aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Asking this question just to be sure, I need to change the name of an existing subnet, in my opinion it should be ok to do it because associations are based on subnet id, is it ok to do it? will it cause any problem?

Comment: Provided nothing downstream is looking anything up by subnet name this should cause no problem.  Canonical AWS work should use ids or, more specifically, ARNs to perform lookups, and names should be transient.

Comment: What do you mean by "Subnet name"? The name is normally stored in a Tag with Key='Name' -- is that what you want to change? That should be fine, since it is just a Tag.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein not the tag but the name we give while creating a subnet, it seems like it is ok to change name, name seems to be transient and all the assosiactions refer to either ARN or the subnet Id.